# How to create a duplicate number series for a column in SQL

Tags: postgresql

The Tablename as `T1`

Need help in writing SQL query for below format using PostgreSQL

```
Code  |  Duplicates

C8028 | 1 
C8028 | 2
C8030 | 1
C8030 | 2
C8030 | 3
C8030 | 4
C8055 | 1
C8055 | 2
```

Comment: Having what as input?

Comment: table T1 with column 'Code' as input. I need output in column 'Duplicate'

Answer (score 2):

Use the [windowing functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html), to rank your rows, partitioned by each change in `Code` like so (Presumably your real table has additional columns, which you will probably want to use as the `ORDER BY`)

```
SELECT "Code", Row_Number() OVER (Partition BY "Code" ORDER BY "Code") AS Duplicates
FROM T1
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/56304/1)